# Argument of maximum value of a table in range

Tags: list-manipulation, maximum

I have

```
data = {{817, 501}, {818, 549}, {819, 562}, {820, 534}, {821, 534}, {822, 535}, {823, 516}};
```

How to find argument "822" for 535 (which is the highest in given range) setting range of maximum to 820-823?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SortBy[Select[data, 820 <= #[[1]] <=  823 &], #[[2]] &][[-1, 1]]`

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility

```
MaximalBy[Select[data, 820 <= First[#] <= 823 &], Last]
(* {{822, 535}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = 
 {{817, 501}, {818, 549}, {819, 562}, {820, 534}, {821, 534}, {822, 535}, {823, 516}};

r = Between[{820, 823}];
```

**1.**

```
First @ First @ TakeLargestBy[Last, 1] @ Cases[data, {a_, _} /; r @ a]
```

822

**2.**

```
First @ Keys @ TakeLargest[1] @ KeySelect[r] @ MapApply[Rule, data]
```

822

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{817, 501}, {818, 549}, {819, 562}, {820, 534},
       {821, 534}, {822, 535}, {823, 516}};
```

---

Using `GroupBy`:

```
GroupBy[data, 820 <= First[#] <= 823 &, Last@SortBy[#, Last] &][True]

(*{{822, 535}}*)
```